# Javascript Profiler in Chrome 79 for Windows: No more mention of optimized or not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

The Javascript profiler in Chrome 79 for Windows seems to no longer mention whether a function has been optimized or not. This used to be available in chart view when rolling over a function. Is this information available any longer? Is it even relevant with Turbofan, nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't surface this information in DevTools anymore. The supported way of profiling JS is through the Performance panel now, but as you say I think it's less relevant to expose optimizations/deoptimization decisions with TurboFan, as there are no hard rules on constructs or patterns that can't be optimized. We don't want to push developers to micro-optimize their code to the compiler.

Another consideration is displaying this info usefully - I suspect the old version that did show optimization info only told you if the function was ever optimized, not that it had been optimized for that specific invocation. To make this info useful you would want to see when the function was optimized, relative to the various invocations. But I think this info is more actionable for V8 developers and not so much for web developers, so we don't expose it.